# $.ajax Where is req.data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I am using node.js. It's a fairly simple file arrangement on a local server.

```
<h3>To Do!</h3>
<ol class="pending>
<li><a class="pending_task" href="localhost://nextstep.html">Task Three</a></li>
<li><a class="pending_task" href="localhost://nextstep.html">Task Five</a></li>
<li><a class="pending_task" href="localhost://nextstep.html">Task Six</a></li>
</ol>
```

and

```
<h3>Completed!</h3>
<ol class="completed">
<li><a class="completed_task" href="localhost://nextstep.html">Task One</a></li>
<li><a class="completed_task" href="localhost://nextstep.html">Task Two</a></li>
<li><a class="completed_task" href="localhost://nextstep.html">Task Four</a></li>
</ol>
```

Are lists on the same page. I finally have the ajax call working as desired, and now I am in the newest glitch.

The $.ajax redirects to the proper url and the connect is made, but there is no data when I do a `console.log(req.data)`

The AJAX call:

```
var newData = "<ol class=\"pending\">" + $('ol.pending').html() + 
            "</ol>" + "<ol class=\"completed\">" + $('ol.completed').html() + "<\ol>";

        $.ajax({
            method:'POST',
            data: newData,
            url: ajax_url,
            success: function(result, status, jqxhr){
                console.log("Response: " + jqxhr.responseText);
                console.log("POST status: " + status);
            },
            dataType: 'html',
        });
```

The app.js

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
  if ((req.method === 'POST') && (req.url === '/result')){
        console.log("Request Data: " + req.data);
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.end("Message Received!");
  }
 }).listen(port, serverURL);
```

My intended result is to rewrite the originating file with the new arrangement of completed/pending, after writing the old arrangement to a new file name (TODO_date_time.html), which I can't do yet because the generated data, passed to the AJAX call is not being transmitted. Or I am not accessing it preoperly.

What I get though is:

```
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Starting Web Server at local:4000
Request Data: undefined
```

The console.log in the browser is all good:

[image: Browser console.log]

Not sure what's wrong with my work at this point.

Comment: Possibly. I will re-visit that entry.

Comment: No. Because I don't need querystring.

Comment: You might wanna check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41521743/774086) to the other question. I explained in details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this

```
var body = ''     
request.on('data', function (data) {
  body += data;
});
```

from Casey Chu's answer in the question that I am possibly duplicating.

Comment: Make sure you do use [`request.setEncoding`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_setencoding_encoding) or else you might have problem with multi-byte characters.

Comment: No. No multibyte characters. I know what the nature of the data is.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need functionality, the suggested duplicate question above has a detailed explanation of simplifying a http server with [Express](http://expressjs.com/).

Otherwise, the problem is that the data is not available yet because it comes in as chunks. To remedy this, event listeners are necessary inside where you detect that it's a POST request to the `/result` endpoint.

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if ((req.method === 'POST') && (req.url === '/result')) {
        console.log("POST request to /result received");

        req.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log('Received data: ', chunk.toString());
        });

        req.on('end', function() {
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.end("Message Received!");
        });

    }
}).listen(port, serverURL);
```

Also, here's a link to a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d0yaypp1/)

Comment: Thanks for the info, however, I don't want to use Express. I want to understand this at a simpler level, not just get results.

Comment: so I need req.on to bind the data?

Comment: I used this from the other question:

  req.on('data', function(data){
   body += data;
   //console.log(data);
  });

Comment: I am taking html as data from the ajax call. Why do I need to stringify it?

Comment: In short, it's because the chunks are buffers of binary data, you need to convert them to a readable representation. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16542217/6407261 for more detail.